# Shell script to expand input string

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I need help on creating a shell script which will take input string and expand as below:

**Input**   =>  **output**

A2B3C4  =>  AABBBCCCC

Comment: Related: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding

Comment: What have you done so far to solve this and what in particular are you stuck at?

Comment: We're not here to do your job or homework, without sharing what you've tried, this is an off-topic question to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ perl -e 'my @F=split //, shift;
           for my $i (0..@F) { print $F[$i] x $F[++$i]};
           print "\n"' A2B3C4
AABBBCCCC
```

This splits the input so that each single character becomes an element in an array (`@F`).  Then, using perl's string multiplier operator (`x`) it prints every even-numbered element (starting at 0) a number of times equal to the next odd-numbered element.

or if you want it to take input from stdin rather than the command line:

```
$ echo $'A2B3C4\nE5F2G7' | perl -ne 'my @F=split //;
    for my $i (0..@F) { print $F[$i] x $F[++$i]};
    print "\n"' 
AABBBCCCC
EEEEEFFGGGGGGG
```

Both of these implementations have the flaw that it only allows single-digit strings and single-digit counts.

The following removes that limitation:

```
$ echo A12B3CZ4 | perl -ne '
    # insert a space between numbers and alphabetic characters.
    s/([[:alpha:]])(\d)/$1 $2/g;
    s/(\d)([[:alpha:]])/$1 $2/g;
    # split on spaces
    @F = split / /;

    for my $i (0..@F) { print $F[$i] x $F[++$i]};
    print "\n"'
AAAAAAAAAAAABBBCZCZCZCZ
```

Answer (score 2):

With Perl you can make it like as shown:

```
  echo a2b3c4 |
  perl -pe 's/(\D)(\d+)/$1x$2/ge'

 aabbbcccc
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy shell implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

char=""
count=""

echo "$1" | while read -n1 -r c; do
    if [ "$char" = "" ]
    then
        char="$c"
        continue
    fi

    if [ "$count" = "" ]
    then
        count="$c"

    for i in $(seq 1 "$count")
    do
        printf "%s" "$char"
    done

    char=""
    count=""

    continue
    fi
done

printf "\n"
```

Example:

```
$ ./transform.sh A2B3C4D0E1
AABBBCCCCE
```

It doesn't work with numbers bigger than 9 though. One would have to
implement some larger logic to distinguish between letters and
numbers.